# bash - loop through array, and re-use array results

Tags: arrays, bash

I am reading a file into an array. This file contains comma delimited data formatted like this:

```
16.01,1.8
20,1.84
25.01,1.9
31.52,1.93
800.1,1.99
1000,1.98
1250,1.98
16000,2
20010,2
```

I need to find the closest number to "1000" in the first column, and I have a working function for that. This number is then used for further processing of the input file, however I can't get this variable until the file has been processed up to that point, which means that the second part of my script only processes the array data after the "1000" point has been found.

The only way I could see to do this, was to open the file a second time with another while loop (unless there is a way to store and re-use the array content?).

My script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    find1k () {
        if ((980<=$freq && $freq<=1050)); then
            scalevolts=$volts
        fi
    }

    while IFS=$',' read -r -a lines; do
        [[ "$lines" =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue

        freq="${lines[0]}"
        volts="${lines[1]}"
        freq=$(printf "%.0f\n" $freq)

        if [ -z "$scalevolts" ]; then
            find1k
        else
# I need to loop through the entire array again from here.
#
            normalised=$(echo "scale=3; ($volts/$scalevolts)"|bc -l)
            echo $freq , $volts , $normalised
        fi
    done < $1
```

Is there a way to do this without having to open the file twice? (i.e. re-use the array content).

bash version is 4.2

Thanks.

Comment: Is the file sorted by the first column?

Comment: Yes, the content is always generated in the same order - first column sorted low to high.

Comment: which part of your script requires to read from first again? Is it the part where you calculate `normalised`?

Comment: @Fazlin - yes - it needs to loop through the entire array again from that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do the whole thing in awk. Then you don't have to worry about only integer arithmetic.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = ","; n=0}
    function abs(x) {
        if (x < 0) return -x
        return x
    }
    /^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/ {next}                # skip comments and blank lines
    n == 0 {min = abs(1000 - $1) }
    {diff = abs(1000 - $1)}
    diff <= min {min = diff; base_voltage = $2}
    {n++; freq[n] = $1; volts[n] = $2}
    END {
        for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
            printf "%s,%s,%.3f\n", freq[i], volts[i], volts[i]/base_voltage
        }
    }
' "$1"
```

outputs

```
16.01,1.8,0.909
20,1.84,0.929
25.01,1.9,0.960
31.52,1.93,0.975
800.1,1.99,1.005
1000,1.98,1.000
1250,1.98,1.000
16000,2,1.010
20010,2,1.010
```

Comment: I just tried this, and rather oddly it prints "inf" as a third parameter. like this: " 16.01,1.8,inf " Another potential issue is that the "1000" can vary ever so slightly either way, which is why my original script searched the array either side of 1000, which I don't think your awk script is doing? I have a reasonably fair understanding of awk, but not quite at your level!

Comment: Ah.. is it this bit "diff = abs(1000 - $1)} diff < prev {one_k = $1" that's doing the checking for 1000?

Comment: that's right. I'm finding the freq that's *closest* to 1000. Your code finds the *last* freq that's between the given range.

Comment: With your "inf" output, the one_k variable must have been zero. I didn't add a check for that in my answer.

Comment: The entire series returns "inf" for the last string. I have to confess that your script largely passes right over my head, so I'm not really able to debug it either. I've had a go, but failed so far.

Comment: Works for me with your test data. How does your real data differ?

Comment: Experimenting, looks like your awk is "mawk". As the first line in the END block before the for loop, put `print "one_k is", one_k`

Comment: It is indeed mawk (but I don't think this is the issue), the comments in the file were causing an issue - however the results are incorrect. They are all the same at 0.002, even with the suggested modification.

Comment: .002 is what you get when you divide a number very close to 2.0 by 1000.

Comment: Ah I see it now - your script divides by the freq variable which is 1000 (rather than the voltage variable AT 1000). No... I need to know the voltage when the frequency is at 1000 - then divide the other voltages by that number - not 1000... If you look carefully at my original script, you'll see that's what it does....

Comment: Got it, updated my answer. Accounts for comments now.

Comment: Thanks - that's now spot on. So much faster than my original script too.

Comment: I tweaked how I found the closest. See where I use variable named "min".

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you're using `read -a` so every line is being read into an array but the contents of this array are overwritten. The elements of `${lines[@]}` only contain the values for the current line, so I guess that `${line[@]}` would be a better name for the variable.

If you want, you can save each part of the line into a separate array like this:

```
freq=()
volts=()

while IFS=, read -r f v rest; do
    freq+=( "$f" )
    volts+= ( "$v" )
    # etc.
done < "$1"
```

But really I think that you're using the wrong tool for the job; the shell is slow at reading files line by line. I would recommend that you use awk instead. If you show us what your desired output is for the input you have shown, then we can help you better.

Comment: Bash arithmetic doesn't handle floats.

Comment: @choroba I know! I wasn't suggesting that it did. I was just showing the OP how to save the values from each line into an array.

Comment: You'll note I was using 'bc' for the maths, not bash, so I don't think that bash not handling floats matters?